# Induced emf and self-inductance: clarification about signs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I'm a little confused.. When I write the equation of the circuit, do I have to keep the signs of the induced emf and self-inductance opposite?

I'll try to explain better my doubt:
Consider a coil that has resistance R and inductance L. Running a current will give rise to both an induced emf and self-inductance, and the situation is:

induced emf= -k

self-inductance= $-L \frac{dI}{dt}$

Now, my question is: the equation of the circuit is given by:

$-k -L \frac{dI}{dt}=RI$

or by

$k -L \frac{dI}{dt}=RI$ ?

Comment: Refer to Lenz's Law: Induced current has a direction such that its magnetic field **opposes** the change in magnetic field induced in the current.

Comment: @Signus and so..?

Comment: @Signus I think that the correct expression is the second, because the self inducted emf opposes to the inducted emf.. do you agree?

Comment: I do believe the second equation is correct as the self-inductance does oppose the induced current already on the wire/coil. That is why I mentioned Lenz's Law. I always think to myself "induction is always in the opposite direction of what my brain thinks."

Comment: Doesn't the term $-LdI/dt$ already account for the induced EMF $E$ so there must be only one of these in the equation?